# Any RaphaelJS Guru knows how to draw this image?

Tags: raphael

Any [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) guru (or any genius who doesn't know Raphael JS) knows how to simply draw this?

[image]

the solid yellow color is 4.2 / 10 of part of the circle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First approach using svg's elliptical arc curve command**

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iwuqe3/edit

```
Raphael.fn.zeroToTenArc = function (x, y, r, value) {

  var set = this.set();
  var pi = Math.PI;
  var cos = Math.cos;
  var sin = Math.sin;
  var maxValue = 10;
  var t = (pi/2) * 3; //translate
  var rad = (pi*2 * (maxValue-value)) / maxValue + t;
  var colors = ["#F79518", "#FCE6BF", "#FFF"];

  set.push(this.circle(x, y, r).attr({ fill : colors[+!value], stroke : 0 }));

  var p = [
    "M", x, y,
    "l", r * cos(t), r * sin(t),
    "A", r, r, 0, +(rad > pi + t), 1, x + r * cos(rad), y + r * sin(rad), 
    "z"
  ];

  set.push(this.path(p).attr({ fill : colors[1], stroke : 0 }));


  set.push(this.circle(x, y, r*0.7).attr({ fill : colors[2], stroke : 0 }));

  return set;
};

var canvas = Raphael("hello", 300, 300);
var arc = canvas.zeroToTenArc(150, 150, 30, 4.2);
```

.

**Second approach using (a lot of) svg's lineto commands**

Demo: http://jsbin.com/usotu5/edit

```
Raphael.fn.zeroToTenArc = function (x, y, radius, value) {
  var angle = 0;
  var endAngle = (value*360)/10;
  var path = "";
  var clockwise = -1;
  var translate = Math.PI/2;

  while(angle <= endAngle) {

    var radians= (angle/180) * Math.PI + translate;
    var cx = x + Math.cos(radians) * radius;
    var cy = y + Math.sin(radians) * radius * clockwise;

    path += (angle === 0) ? "M" : "L";
    path += [cx,cy];
    angle += 1;
  }

  return this.path(path);
};

var canvas = Raphael("hello", 200, 200);

canvas.zeroToTenArc(50, 50, 30, 10).attr({ stroke : "#FCE6BF", "stroke-width" : 12 });
canvas.zeroToTenArc(50, 50, 30, 4.2).attr({ stroke : "#F79518", "stroke-width" : 12 });
```

Comment: how about the text, do you use something like `var t = paper.text(50, 50, 4.2).attr({fill: "#f00", "font-size" : "15px"});` to do it?  I wasn't sure which to use to set the color.  If I use the `stroke` it actually gave me 2 colors, one on top of another. (black on top of the color I wanted).

Comment: Also, another thing is, there are two sizes, one big and one small, and the small one is to be contained in 50 x 50 div, so I used radius of 22 and a stroke-width of 6, and the edges appear somewhat rugged... I guess it is the result of no anti-aliasing? (also because this is a stronger color vs white background) Is there a way to make it smoother? My sample is http://jsbin.com/usotu5/3/edit

Comment: + i added your text to the demo. it fits perfectly imho. http://jsbin.com/usotu5/4/edit

+ anti-aliasing could be a problem. sry, i have no idea. pitfalls exists depending on your browser+platform. eg chrome on windows has a bug with stroke color.

Comment: maybe the `circle` method do a better job of anti-aliasing... so SVG doesn't have a way to draw arc in a nice way but need to rely on a series of "Move to" and "Line to"? (lots of them!)

Comment: you're right. currently it's kind of a quick and dirty hack, so i came up with a new approach based on svg's arc method. could you plz check this out? for me it looks good on mac/chrome. http://jsbin.com/iwuqe3/edit

Comment: I tried the first one you added on IE 7 and it is showing a blinking cursor...  no circle... so this is only for SVG, not VML?  Raphael can support something specific to SVG but not VML?

Comment: a blinking cursor doesn't make sense to me. any error messages? i tested the code on IE6/8/9* and it works. *)unfortunately not on IE7